# Radio button generator , getting values

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic, radio-button

Here is the deal, I have to do a dynamic survey and I got the idea to put a variable as the name of the radio buttons but it's kind of tricky to insert it in base.

Why dynamic? Let's say if someone add a new question it will automatically generated the radio buttons row without need of change the code again.

The purpose of this code: Generate a set of radio buttons for each new question or question that is in database and saved the selected radio button's value for each row without getting conflict.

Example: if I check radio button 1 I get value 1 at this question for row 3 and if I check radio button 2 I get value 2 at the question at row 5.

PS: This code is only the testing code of radio buttons.

The *PROBLEM* is that i don t really know how to record all values of every row of the selected radio buttons , the insert work , it takes the first value but not the others of the next rows so if you could give me a solution or an advice , i think i need to do a loop on the insert to check each row to get each value of the selected radio button . The form is like :

column 1: Question: ... // column 2: Radio button set //  column 3:Commentary

```
//Main form// 
<?php
$msgerror = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs ";    
if(isset($_POST["bouton10"])){
  $link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
  $id = $_REQUEST["Picolo4"];
  $Nom = $_REQUEST["Picolo1"];
  $Prenom = $_REQUEST["Picolo2"];
  $Email = $_REQUEST["Picolo3"];

  if ($id !="" &&   $Nom !="" && $Prenom !="" && $Email !=""){         
    $recherche= "SELECT Ref,Question,Choix,Commentara FROM questionnaire WHERE Qref ='$id'";
    mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
    $un = 0;
    $result= mysqli_query($link,$recherche);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $Ref =$row["Ref"];
      $Question = $row["Question"];
      $un  = $un+1;
      echo" <tr bgcolor=\"white\">
      <td>$Question position: $un </td>
      <td>
        <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"3\">
        <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"2\">
        <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"1\">
        <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\"  value = \"0\">
        <input type=\"radio\" name =\"$un\" id =\"un\" value = \"0\">
      </td>
      <td width = \"60\"> <textarea> </textarea> </td> 
    </tr>                          
    </div>
    </div>
    ";
  }
  else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msgerror')</script>";
  }
}
?>

//Insert part //
<?php
  $link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
  $msgerror = "Veuillez remplir tous les champs ";
  if(isset($_POST["bouton10"])){
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
    if ($id !="" && $Nom !="" && $Prenom !="" && $Email !=""){
      $id = $_REQUEST["Picolo4"];
      $Nom = $_REQUEST["Picolo1"];
      $Prenom = $_REQUEST["Picolo2"];
      $Email = $_REQUEST["Picolo3"];
      $enregistrer= "Insert INTO client(Client_nom,Client_prenom,Client_email) VALUES('$Nom','$Prenom','$Email')";

      mysqli_query($link,$enregistrer);
    }
  }
?>
<?php
  $link=Mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);
  $un = 1;
  if(isset($_POST["bouton11"])){
    $choix = $_POST["$un"];
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$login,$pass,$dbname);  
    $enregistrer= "INSERT INTO questionnaire(Choix)  VALUES('$choix')";
    mysqli_query($link,$enregistrer);
  }
?>
```

Comment: So what's  the problem? Is there any error or anything else??

Comment: Anyone could help me please ? I m on this since 3 days now .